# CSS transition from left to right starting from the center

Tags: html, css, css-animations

How do I make sure that the span starting from the center expands up and down. I do not know if I have explained myself, I attach the code so you can understand what I mean. Is there anyone who can help me?

```css
body {
    font: caption;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
 
.first_switcher {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: dimgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  position: relative;
}
 
.first_switcher__input2{
  display: none;
}
.first_switcher__input1 {
  display: none;
}
 
.first_switcher__label1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}

.first_switcher__label2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}
 
.first_switcher__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 38px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 14px;
  transition: left 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}

.first_switcher__input1:checked + .first_switcher__label1 {
  color: white;
}
.first_switcher__input2:checked + .first_switcher__label2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  color: white;
}

.first_switcher__input1:not(:checked) + .first_switcher__label1 {
  color: transparent;
}
.first_switcher__input2:checked ~ .first_switcher__toggle {
  -webkit-transition: width 2s, height 2s;
    transition: width 2s, height 2s;
  
  height: 38px;
  width: 200px; 
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_switcher">
                <input type="radio" name="balance" id="on" class="first_switcher__input1" checked/>
                    <label for="on" class="first_switcher__label1">ON</label>
      
                <input type="radio" name="balance" id="off" class="first_switcher__input2"/>
                    <label for="off" class="first_switcher__label2">OFF</label>
      
                <span class="first_switcher__toggle"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Riccardo, you should consider isolating your issue and posting again. It is challenging and time consuming for people to look through your entire code to pin down an error. See StackOverflow's guidelines for posting [minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate width/height and also top at the same time to keep the element in the center while growing

```css
body {
  font: caption;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.first_switcher {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 38px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: dimgray;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  position: relative;
}

.first_switcher__input2 {
  display: none;
}

.first_switcher__input1 {
  display: none;
}

.first_switcher__label1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}

.first_switcher__label2 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: color 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}

.first_switcher__toggle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 38px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 38px;
  left: 0; /* updated */
  top: 50%; /* updated */
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1);
  will-change: transform;
}

.first_switcher__input1:checked+.first_switcher__label1 {
  color: white;
}

.first_switcher__input2:checked+.first_switcher__label2 {
  transition-delay: 1s;
  color: white;
}

.first_switcher__input1:not(:checked)+.first_switcher__label1 {
  color: transparent;
}

.first_switcher__input2:checked~.first_switcher__toggle {
  transition: all 2s; /* updated */
  height: 38px; 
  width: 200px;
  left: 0; /* updated */
  top: calc(50% - 19px); /* updated */
}
```

```html
<div class="first_switcher">
  <input type="radio" name="balance" id="on" class="first_switcher__input1" checked/>
  <label for="on" class="first_switcher__label1">ON</label>

  <input type="radio" name="balance" id="off" class="first_switcher__input2" />
  <label for="off" class="first_switcher__label2">OFF</label>

  <span class="first_switcher__toggle"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want the animation to start from the left and centered in height

Comment: @RiccardoCamera in this case, keep left:0 in both states

Comment: @RiccardoCamera good and since you are new I will remind you that it's good to mark the answer as accepted if it solves your issue so that the question get removed from the unnaswered queue .. Of course your aren't obliged to do and you can keep it like that in case you are waiting for more anwsers and more alternatives.